# Run another yarn/npm task within a package.json, without specifying yarn or npm

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I have a task in my package.json "deploy", which needs to first call "build". I have specified it like this:

> "deploy": "yarn run build; ./deploy.sh",

The problem is that this hard codes `yarn` as the package manager. So if someone doesn't use `yarn`, it doesn't work. Switching to `npm` causes a similar issue.

What's a good way to achieve this while remaining agnostic to the choice of `npm` or `yarn`?

Comment: Rico's answer made me think of something.. There is a concern over hard coding 'tools', what if someone with Windows wanted to run this? `.sh` wouldn't work... food for thought I suppose...

Comment: Yeah, but that's in the category of having to do significant extra work to support a second platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have a much simpler solution:

```
"deploy": "yarn run build || npm run build; ./deploy.sh",
```

Its only real downside is in the case where yarn exists, but the build fails, then `npm run build` will also take place.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to use the [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) package, whose documentation states:

> Yarn Compatibility
>
> If a script is invoked with Yarn, npm-run-all will correctly use Yarn to execute the plan's child scripts.

So you can do this:

```json
"predeploy": "run-s build",
"deploy": "./deploy.sh",
```

And the `predeploy` step will use either npm or yarn depending on how you invoked the `deploy` task.

I think it is good to have the runs in package.json remain package manager agnostic so that they aren't tied to a specific package manager, but within a project, it is probably prudent to agree on the use of a single package manager so that you're not dealing with conflicting lockfiles.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not ideal, but you could run a `.js` file at your project root to make these checks...

You could create a file at your project root called `yarnpm.js` (or whatever), and call said file in your `package.json` `deploy` command..

```
// package.json (trimmed)
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "node yarnpm",
  "build": "whatever build command you use"
},
```

```js
// yarnpm.js
const fs = require('fs');

const FILE_NAME = process.argv[1].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

// Command you wish to run with `{{}}` in place of `npm` or `yarn'
// This would allow you to easily run multiple `npm`/`yarn` commands without much work
// For example, `{{}} run one && {{}} run two
const COMMAND_TO_RUN = '{{}} run build; ./deploy.sh';

try {
  if (fs.existsSync('./package-lock.json')) {  // Check for `npm`
    execute(COMMAND_TO_RUN.replace('{{}}', 'npm'));
  } else if (fs.existsSync('./yarn.lock')) {   // Check for `yarn`
    execute(COMMAND_TO_RUN.replace('{{}}', 'yarn'));
  } else {
    console.log('\x1b[33m', `[${FILE_NAME}] Unable to locate either npm or yarn!`, '\033[0m');
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log('\x1b[31m', `[${FILE_NAME}] Unable to deploy!`, '\033[0m');
}

function execute(command) { // Helper function, to make running `exec` easier
  require('child_process').exec(command,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps in some way! Cheers.

---

***EDIT:***

...or if you wanted to parameterize the `yarnpm.js` script, to make it easily reusable, and to keep all "commands" inside the `package.json` file, you could do something like this..

```
// package.json (trimmed, parameterized)
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "node yarnpm '{{}} run build; ./deploy.sh'",
    "build": "node build.js"
},
```

```js
// yarnpm.js (parameterized)
const COMMAND_TO_RUN = process.argv[2]; // Technically, the first 'parameter' is the third index
const FILE_NAME = process.argv[1].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

if (COMMAND_TO_RUN) {
  const fs = require('fs');

  try {
    if (fs.existsSync('./package-lock.json')) {  // Check for `npm`
      execute(COMMAND_TO_RUN.replace('{{}}', 'npm'));
    } else if (fs.existsSync('./yarn.lock')) {   // Check for `yarn`
      execute(COMMAND_TO_RUN.replace('{{}}', 'yarn'));
    } else {
      console.log('\x1b[33m', `[${FILE_NAME}] Unable to locate either npm or yarn!`, '\033[0m');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('\x1b[31m', `[${FILE_NAME}] Unable to deploy!`, '\033[0m');
  }

  function execute(command) { // Helper function, to make running `exec` easier
    require('child_process').exec(command,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
          return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          return;
        }
        console.log(stdout);
      });
  }
} else {
  console.log('\x1b[31m', `[${FILE_NAME}] Requires a single argument!`, '\033[0m')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if check before run?

You can create a new file called `build.sh`, and it's content below:

```sh
# check if current user installed node environment, if not, auto install it.
if command -v node >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "version of node: $(node -v)"
    echo "version of npm: $(npm -v)"
else
    # auto install node environment, suppose platform is centos, 
    # need change this part to apply other platform.
    curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
    yum -y install nodejs
fi

npm run build
```

Then your script will be:

```
{
  "deploy": "./build.sh && ./deploy.sh"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I really don't like the idea of auto-installing node as part of a build script. Seems completely surprising and liable to mess with someone's system in unexpected ways.